# How to get information about failed app install in Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Currently i'm trying to create a teams app for our company. I used a demo app from the official samples, and created a manifest.zip what contains twoo images and the manifest file itself.
I uploaded it to teams and the IT-Guys enabled it to a test tenant, as written in the manifest.

The app has shown in teams and i'm tried to install it. But i just got "Something went wrong" bei using the "Add" button.

Is there any chance to find out, what happend? Does Teams store Logs on any location?

I tried to add it to my teams account and read the docs.

Comment: This error sometimes occurs when you do not add Microsoft Teams in channels inside bot channel registration. Also could you please check if you see anything in console logs?

Comment: Indeed. The bot registration was pending in organization. So it wasnt found. Thnaks